# Is every element of the tensor algebra a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

So given a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ (say over the real or complex numbers), we can consider its dual space $V^*$. Then  we can consider multilinear maps from p copies of $V^*$ and q copies of $V$ into the underlying field. These multilinear maps are the p-q tensors on V. They form a vector space $T^p_qV$, since we can add them and multiply by elements of the underlying field, and still get another element in $T^p_qV$.

Now if we take just the p-0 tensors, we can consider their direct sum, from 0 to infinity, to form the vector space $TV$, which, when we endow with the tensor product forms the tensor algebra.

If anything above is wrong, please correct me.

My quesiton is that now a general element in the tensor algebra will be a sum of tensor of differnt ranks. And so it is ill-defined how many dual vectors the overall object would need to be fed to output an element in the underlying field. And so in general an element in the tensor algebra isn't a well-defined tensor.

I am not sure whether my definition of tensor, or of tensor algebra, or both, is wrong. Please can someone clarify.

(I don't think it matters, but the reason I was going through this was while trying to learn about Clifford Algebras and Spinors and such things.)

Comment: You are correct, not all elements of tensor product are tensors. They are sums of tensors. But it seems you already know that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question. I agree with freakish now. Tensors are only the 'homogeneous elements' of the tensor algebra, so the elements of $T_p^q$ for some $p$ and $q$ (including 0).

Comment: It's just a name, but I generally would prefer to call any element in a tensor product $V\otimes W$ a tensor, note you are also calling $T^p_qV$ as the space of $(p,q)$-tensors and the homogeneous elements would be called *pure tensors*. But it's not important.

Comment: You can apply a mixed tensor to any number of vectors/covectors, it's just that the most natural way to do this is to apply linearity and then say the result is zero when applying a homogeneous component to a sequence of vectors/covectors that doesn't match.

Comment: These are **answers** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.